# polkadot-js: What does targets mean in api.query.staking.nominators?

Tags: polkadot-js

code:

```
const nominators = await api.query.staking.nominators.entries();
```

example json output for nominators vaiable:

```
[
  [
    [
      "145xupEFYa81KCexCH5bRU6k3fqY9GgLWAH8nMhat2CKHkcd"
    ],
    {
      "targets": [
        "12gPFmRqnsDhc9C5DuXyXBFA23io5fSGtKTSAimQtAWgueD2",
        "13Q48Ep3PVpvXA1BeVcUhNJerLshsaeq4EdgPUHnemqJYmND",
        "13s9RrQSFbnp2TneY7nkdLmGc3ijBw12YQct8pc8km36Z9hg",
        "14bUYpiF2oxVpmXDnFxBipSi4m9zYBThMZoLpY8bRQrPQNG1",
        "15wepZh1jWNqxBjsgErm8HmYiE21n79c5krQJeTsYAjHddeM",
        "16DKyH4fggEXeGwCytqM19e9NFGkgR2neZPDJ5ta8BKpPbPK",
        "13RENAu9cpMpxp3EYzWFGpZXgvMZGDrnconYugNdynQz1sDQ",
        "14Y626iStBUWcNtnmH97163BBJJ2f7jc1piGMZwEQfK3t8zw",
        "16YwUZyLdeAoe4KmhivGwuuJpBH1US4qkUtXK2V83MVXUy6x",
        "14BeKcfcvJSJjvu9GZ2CA8EQ3XkK9J1HdwDrfz5Sg5ERDnrP",
        "124X3VPduasSodAjS6MPd5nEqM8SUdKN5taMUUPtkWqF1fVf",
        "127nWP7adKAsXBW135FrBgmt5mxuFA5YpXSrdD6BWp6RUoHs",
        "1EWbJs2jdh34mhH8ovwQTNiLmQ87mMksJW3raRMxk6WXY29",
        "15UyiZ9rYhrX39Rasc1iE4sdME7WHNFSj8RQT3yuuytd3Nrd",
        "15cfSaBcTxNr8rV59cbhdMNCRagFr3GE6B3zZRsCp4QHHKPu",
        "148Ta5cWD3wekK3C6EbdDhYrdxC5e71VTKQCjmHUjE1DCG31"
      ],
      "submittedIn": "813",
      "suppressed": false
    }
  ],...
```

I thought that the targets were validators which the nominator voted for, but that doesn't always seem to be the case.

What do these targets represent?

Comment: Can you give an example when this is not the case?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Is this a list of all validators a nominator has staked with in the past (not adjusted for unbonding)? I was confused because many of the targets are not validators when you check subscan, but I think that's because they are simply no longer validators.

Comment: It is not constantly updated. If a user nominates some people a long time ago, never updates their nominations, and the validators drop out, then the storage will be in a stale state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from the [staking Rust code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ea4f532cffde1b90651d8f1be13a10c3721dd3d3/frame/staking/src/lib.rs#L677-L678).

It means what validators this nominator is nominating.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. If you check subscan it will show you that many of those targets are no longer supported by the nominator; some of them aren't even validators anymore. I think that this is a list of all validators the nominator has nominated for.

Comment: The nominators set those targets. That's a list they want to nominate. We could say they are nominating those validators from some point of view because the nominator selects them and clicks the nominate button.

And what you said is the result of the election.